# Can't get my simple Lorentz factor calculator to work with decimals. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator that calculates Lorentz factor in c#. But it doesn't seem to work with decimals. I've only done the first part of the calculator:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int c = 299792458;

            Console.Write("speed: ");
            string speed = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Gammafaktor: ");
            string Gammafaktor = Console.ReadLine();


            {
            }
            int gamma1 = Convert.ToInt32(Gammafaktor);
            int speed1 = Convert.ToInt32(speed);

            if (gamma1 != 0)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(1 / (Math.Sqrt(1 - ((speed1 * speed1) / (1)))));

            }



        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, please reformat your code, I don't think it will work if I paste it in vs... second if you want to calculate with decimals, user `double` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the factor of your number would be high, I advice you to use `Decimal`

> Decimals have much higher precision and are usually used within monetary (financial) applications that require a high degree of accuracy.
>   [Reference](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html)

Besides lorenz factor uses `1 / sqrt(1 - v*v)`

```
var calc = 1m / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Sqrt(1 - speed1*speed1));
```

Comment: `double` for *physical* not *finance* world

Comment: thank you for your help i can now input decimals but when i use var    " calc = 1m / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Sqrt(1 - speed1*speed1));" i get error cannot convert decimal to double

Comment: got it it was supposed to be `var calc = 1m / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Sqrt((double)(1 - speed1 * speed1)));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate with decimals, then you need to use `Double` data type instead of an `Integer`.

An `int` has a range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and a `double` has a range from +-5.0 x 10-324 to +-1.7 x 10308.

You see that a `int` can't handle decimals.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide by 1 instead of c under the square root, this means that you measure speed in units of c, not in m/s. Consequently, the numerical value of velocity must be a fraction of 1. 
However, your variable `speed1` is an integer.